# What is the FTC of a function from the perspective of Stokes' theorem?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, stokes-theorem

In the case of $\int_a^b f(x) dx=F(b) - F(a)$ this can be written as $\int_a^b \frac d {dx} F(x) dx=F(b)- F(a).$

Comparing to Stokes' theorem, $\int_{\partial\Omega} \omega=\int_\Omega d\omega$ where $d\omega$ is a differential form, I guess it would be something like

$$\int_{\Omega=[a,b]} dF=\int_{\partial\Omega=\{a,b\}} F$$?

So the manifold $\Omega$ is the compact interval $[a,b]$ over which the exterior derivative $dF$ is integrated, whereas the boundary consists of the set of the two limit points $\partial\Omega=\{a,b\}$ over which the differential form $F$ is integrated.

---

PS: [Great explanation](https://youtu.be/UwfGNs41IhY):

[image]

Comment: $dF = F'dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_{\{a,b\}} = \int_{\{a\}^- \cup \{b\}^+} = \int_{\{b\}} - \int_{\{a\}}$.

Comment: What are you trying to learn about this case?  Why it works or how the integrals on the boundary work? I would like to elaborate the answer a bit more without getting too long winded.

Comment: Yes, your observation is correct.

Comment: @openproblem I see the idea, but I would like to understand the equivalence (to the extent that it is possible) between the manifold in Stokes', the differential form, and the most standard enunciation of FTC for a scalar univariable function. I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Here goes the problem of the orientation of the interval $[a, b]$. I guess they solved it by writing $$ I = \int_{\{a\} ^{-} \cup \{b\}^{+}} F$$. Remember $$\int_{A_1 \cup A_2} = \int_{A_1} + \int_{A_2}$$. So, $$ I = \int_{\{b\}} F - \int_{\{a\}} F = F|_a^b $$ where $a < b$. The main idea is behind the last term, appearing in Newton-Leibniz formula. What would you like to become aware of?

Comment: @sergeiivanov What is $\{a\} ^{-} \cup \{b\}^{+}$ and $A_1 \cup A_2$?

Comment: I do not know how it is called, but the operator $\cup$ is called the union; in other words, it unites two subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$ to get their union $A = A_1 \cup A_2$. The $\{a\}^{-} $ denotes the set of one-single element $a$ oriented negatively. Hence, there arises the minus sign. The same story with $\{b\} ^{+} $

Comment: I just make another comment: The FTC was proved through the definition of derivative with the usage of well-known Lagrange theorem. The tendency, why we have to prove but not deduce, was seen while treating definite integrals as limits of Riemann sums. Compute definite integrals for some functions by definition and you might wish to prove FTC. The Stokes theorem might stem from Green one and Divergence. So, as you can see, the generalised Stokes theorem imply $n$-dimensional differential forms and manifolds. It remains true for FTC, so it genralizes it but ideas are different!

Comment: This is why the expression $F(x) |_a^b$ remains only for one dimensional case. How would you compute $$\iint_{[a, b] \times[c, d]} d^2 F(x, y) = F|_{[a, b] \times [c, d]}? $$ No way! Of course, there is formula but it is deduced from FTC (have to use it twice and is valid only if the domain of integration is rectangular ). You might wish to think of it as an integral over the boundary of the rectangular domain $[a, b] \times[c, d] $

Comment: From this you want to produce line integrals over segments which are edges of the rectangle and so these integral are likely to be evaluated over boundary. Then you generalise the integration by parts formula to multiple integrals by applying it to rectangular domain once, after which obtaining $$\int_c^d \int_a^b v \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dxdy = \int_\Gamma uv \cos \alpha - \int_c^d \int_a^b u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} dxdy$$. See how the expression $uv|_a^b$ changed to line integral. From this, you get Green theorem, Divergence one and even Stokes one. But you see the idea

Comment: Next, see that the integral over the compact set boils down to the integral over the boundary of the set. The perplexing thing is the definitions of manifolds... So, I am done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the choice of F, dF/dx = f(x). In the vocabulary of differential forms, this is saying that f(x) dx is the exterior derivative of the 0-form, namely the function, F. In other words, that dF = f dx. The general Stokes theorem applies to higher differential forms ω instead of just 0-forms such as F.

A closed interval [a, b] is a simple example of a one-dimensional manifold with boundary. Its boundary is the set consisting of the two points a and b. Integrating f over the interval may be generalized to integrating forms on a higher-dimensional manifold. In the more general case, the manifold has to be orientable, and the form has to be compactly supported in order to give a well-defined integral.

The Orientation of the interval can be thought of as the ordering of the elements, the closed bounded interval [a,b] is compact as you learn in analysis.

The two points a and b form the boundary of the closed interval. More generally, Stokes' theorem applies to oriented manifolds M with boundary. The boundary ∂M of M is itself a manifold and inherits a natural orientation from M. Intuitively, a inherits the opposite orientation as b, as they are at opposite ends of the interval. So, "integrating" F over two boundary points a, b is taking the difference F(b) − F(a).

This integrating over two points is really more of a degenerate case and maybe it is confusing as to why you are just plugging in the values.

You can understand it as integrating over a singleton using an atomic measure with the two point boundary. An atomic measure gives a non-zero measure to the singleton set so that taking an integral over a singleton makes sense in a way that is more than just hand waving.

Comment: A singleton is a set with only one element?

Comment: Yes. A singleton is a set with only one element.

Comment: Ahh... This may be what Sergei just explained as $\{a\}^-$ and $\{b\}^+$? So two singletons with an atomic measure on each?

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate Yes.